# First person controller getting stuck on walls

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I'm working on a voxel based project similar to minecraft and i'm running into an issue with my first person controller.

http://pastebin.com/XaFCM8zC --> I'll post the whole thing so nothing important is left out.

I have this OnCollisionStay method that detects the angle of the wall I'm running into (AKA i dont want to be able to run up 90 degree walls, or be able to spam jump to climb mountains)

```
void OnCollisionStay(Collision collision){
    foreach (ContactPoint contactPoint in collision.contacts) {
        groundNormal += contactPoint.normal;
        if (contactPoint.normal.y > Mathf.Cos (slopeLimit * Mathf.Deg2Rad)) {
            tooSteep = false;
        }
    }
    if (collision.contacts.Length > 0) {
        groundNormal /= collision.contacts.Length;
    }
    grounded = true;
}
```

It works correctly, but the problem arises in my FixedUpdate method where I limit my movement code via this line:

```
    if (!tooSteep || !grounded) {
```

so I can only move if its not to steep, or I'm not grounded, but I'm trying to make it where I can move wherever, just not walk/jump up walls.

I tried making a "canJump" variable but that only solves part of it. **How can I prevent user input from affecting y velocity if the user is colliding with a wall that is too steep?**

Answer (score 0):

Called up a buddy of mine and he stated the obvious i overlooked.

Apparently unity's default colliders have some level of friction on them. I just created a physics material with 0 coefficients for both types of friction and its working as intended, i just need to limit the wall jumping which isn't a problem.

Hopefully this helps someone in the future.